# My player used to move well, but one day I opened the editor and nothing worked

Tags: unity-game-engine, unity3d-editor

I made a script to move the player, my intention is to made a slippery movement like in ice, it used to work, but one day I opened the editor and didn't work for some reason, the only fixes i've been able to discover created an awful movement.

```
    using System.Collections;
    using System.Collections.Generic;
    using UnityEngine;

    public class PlayerController : MonoBehaviour
    {
        Rigidbody rb;
        [SerializeField] float speed;
        [SerializeField] Vector2 rawMovement;
        [SerializeField] Vector3 movement;
        [SerializeField] Vector3 DEBUG_velocity;

        // Start is called before the first frame update
        void Start()
        {
            rb = GetComponent<Rigidbody>();
        }

        // Update is called once per frame
        void Update()
        {
            rawMovement = new Vector2(InputManager.Instace.GetNormalMovement().x, InputManager.Instace.GetNormalMovement().y);
            movement = new Vector3(rawMovement.x * speed, 0, rawMovement.y * speed);
            rb.AddForce(movement);
            DEBUG_velocity = rb.velocity;
        }
    }
```

Images:
[Rigidbody component](https://i.stack.imgur.com/y247j.png)
[Player script](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oWXF1.png)

Video showing up what is happening:
[Video](https://streamable.com/fd5kv8)

My objective was to make a slippery movement, like ice, I tried changing the force type, the speed amaount, tweaking the variables but none worked, my only results were a blocky movement

EDIT: I tried moving the AddForce() to FixedUpdate() but didn't work

Comment: Don't add force in update, use Fixed Update for physics

Comment: Try changing the interpolation on the Rigidbody, I think that should solve your issue if you're getting janky movement

Comment: Didn't work either, I tried with every type of interpolation

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I managed to find the error, I had to ask in unity's discord.
Turns out it was the object called "CameraLimits" it had a box collider and the player was inside it.

Comment: Hello, could you please share the code how it should look like.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: @Endery, it didn't had anything to do with the code, i had a box collider and the player was inside it, so it couldn't move, i just deleted the box collider and fixed it